# How do I reference a datatype defined in a different .swift file?

Tags: swift, enums

I'm unable to access a datatype declared in a separate .swift file.

Scenario: 
I have two .swift files: 
a) envSwift.swift and 
b) mySwift.swift

'**envSwift.swift**' has my assorted data types, including an enum (which are defined as themselves, outside of any class):

[image]

**mySwift.swift**:

[image]

I'm getting the compiler error: "**Use of unresolved identifier 'FKPermission'**".

How do I use (refer to) a *public* datatype defined in a different .swift file?

---

**Hint:** when I do a copy/paste of enum FKPermission into the top of mySwift.swift & compile, 
I get the following compiler error: "**Invalid redeclaration of 'FKPermission'**"; even though I can't access it.  
So the original enum is detected, but 'unresolved'.

Comment: Missing a dot before `MyPermissionRead` when assigning to `myPermission`?

Comment: I've added the enum.member qualifiers and still no change.  I've replaced the .swift texts with screen snapshots; see above.

Comment: Are they both included in the same application target? Have you tried cleaning and deleting Xcode's Derived Data folder?

Comment: Yes.  Same target.
I've deleted the derived data & did an option-clean of build folder.
Same problem.

Answer (score 7):

Although you say that both files are in the same target, maybe one of them is *also* in another target (e.g. your test target)?
That would be leading to exactly the errors you're describing:

1) the 'unresolved identifier' error (compiling the test target)

2) when copy/pasting the declarations - the 'redeclaration' error (compiling the main target).

So perhaps the solution is: add `envSwift.swift` to your test target, too.

Comment: You are right. In my case the issue was that I added the swift file with the enum declaration to the Test target. So the enums were not recognized in the test class.